# how to use -exec on the find command with xonsh?

Tags: python, shell, xonsh

In xonsh I can run a `find` command like this:

```
find @(str(path)) -iname "log.txt"
```

Where path is a pathlib.Path object.

However, I don't understand how to use the `-exec` and `-execdir` options on `find`:

```
find @(str(path)) -iname "log.txt" -execdir pwd {} \;
```

This results in the error:

```
SyntaxError: <xonsh-code>:1:5: ('code: @(',)
```

I reviewed [Tutorial — xonsh 0.10.1.dev5.dev5 documentation](https://xon.sh/tutorial.html#python-evaluation-with) and tried @$(...) and numerous other variations without any success.

Edit: this version

```
find @(str(path)) -iname "log.txt" -execdir pwd '{}' \;
```

gives this error:

```
find: missing argument to `-execdir'
```

Comment: I suspect the `{}` is confusing `xonsh`, as it's a valid `dict` literal. Try quoting it (`... -execdir pwd '{}' \;`).

Comment: @chepner. I already tried quoting it like you suggest. It gives the error: find: missing argument to `-execdir'

Comment: Oh: you may to quote `;` as well. `xonsh` doesn't support backslash escapes, so `find` is seeing the literal string `\;`, not the expected `;`. I'm not sure how `xonsh` treats `;`, so while `';'` should be fine, `;` alone may also work. To be clear: your new error message is from `find` itself, not `xonsh`, so your *shell* syntax is fine.

Comment: (`\;` is a POSIX shell requirement, as without the backslash the `;` would be a command terminator, rather than an argument to `find`.)

Comment: @chepner - thanks. I have to quote both separately like `-execdir pwd '{}' ';'`

Comment: What do you expect `pwd` to do? It's a command that prints the current working directory, and as such, does not need or use a filename argument. If you just want to see each directly that contains a `log.txt` file, `-execdir pwd ';'` should suffice.

Comment: It gets it; the error message is telling you that `pwd` is explicitly *ignoring* it. The purpose of calling `pwd` here is to see what the current directory is when `pwd` is executed by `-execdir`. It doesn't need the filename (represented by `{}`) that triggered the call to do that.

Comment: Call something simple like `pwd foo` on the command line and see what happens.

Comment: @chepner: it is working as expected. My mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding the answer here for future reference:

This `bash`

```sh
find ~/.local/lib/python3.8/ -iname "*ygments*pyc" -exec ls -ahtlr {} \;
```

becomes this `xonsh` it seems...

```py
find ~/.local/lib/python3.8 -iname "*ygments*pyc"  -exec ls -ahltr "{}" ";"
```

Though this also seem to work :-D :

```py
 for i in !(find ~/.local/lib/python3.8 -iname "*ygments*pyc"):
     ls -ahtlr @(i.strip())
```